# History not working in bash

Tags: bash, history-expansion

When I type at the bash prompt

```bash
!5
```

... I simply get

```
!5: command not found
```

... as the response.  Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?  Anything I should check?

Comment: Try this: `set -o histexpand` or `set -o history ; set -o histexpand`

Comment: Now I get a different error "bash: !5: event not found"

Comment: Are you working directly on the terminal? Or how are you running that command? Because `!5` might fails if do not have enough entries in your history. Press `history` and you will get the list of all  executed commands

Comment: If you cannot remember the exact format of a command it’s helpful to use the history as you are trying to do. If you want to use `journalctl` and have used it before then `history | grep journalctl` will show all the previous commands you have used containing `journalctl`. If you don’t have a command number 5 in the history !5 will not work. Searching as described above will show things that are in the history and so should work. I actually have an alias set up so my command shortens to `hs journalctl`